# Visualizer for evtest logs

Tags: linux, touch-screen, touch, multi-touch

I'm looking for a tool that can visualize or make it a bit easier to interpret the logs that are produced from the `evtest` tool. I've googled for several times and could not find such a tool to visualizing this type of logs.

Or if there are other ways to accomplish this, they are also welcome!

context: it is for tracing touch events on an embedded platform, so I cannot visualize the touch events on the device itself.

An small example of the logs:

```
Event: time 1639053130.673153, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1639053130.673153, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 0
Event: time 1639053130.673153, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 161
Event: time 1639053130.673153, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 1117
Event: time 1639053130.673153, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR), value 128
Event: time 1639053130.673153, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1639053130.755542, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 162
Event: time 1639053130.755542, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 1118
Event: time 1639053130.755542, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you just run any program that paints dots where you touch your touch surface, but on a remote X server?

Comment: The device that has the touch screen does not have an X server, it uses a Qt application that reads the touch events directly.

Comment: and setting `DISPLAY` so that Qt displays on a remote X server over network can't work?